# A war file created for weblogic server. Is that same war file work in WebSphere?

Tags: deployment, websphere, weblogic, web-deployment

A war file created from weblogic server. Is that same war file work in websphere Server

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. Depends on if any weblogic-specific features were used, or if you stuck to the servlet spec.

Comment: So simple application like hello world will RUN both server?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes.